# When exactly did Mason sing for Pink Floyd?

Tags: pink-floyd

The following quote is taken from the wikipedia page about [Scream Thy Last Scream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scream_Thy_Last_Scream):

> The song features several changes in tempo, a sped-up double-tracked vocal part by Barrett, while drummer Nick Mason simultaneously sings the normal part (one of only 4 moments he ever sang on a Floyd record)

Which are the other three tracks in which Mason sings in a Pink Floyd record? Wikipedia quotes Inside Out, written by Mason himself, as a source for the number four, so the answer to my question might also be in there, but I don't have a copy available at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

He sings on:

- [*Merry Xmas Song*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBgv20hgnY0) (1975).
- [*Corporal Cleg*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oH5fI0qpLu4) (1968).
- [*One of These Days*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48PJGVf4xqk) (1971).
- [*Scream Thy Last Scream*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSz2bDE6ukw) (written in 1965, released in 2016).